Status callback in async Common API with SOME/ip
Is there a way to make an async call in Common API call a callback to report the status of RPC execution. For example, if there is a RPC that is long running, I would like to report the progress of its execution.
Thanks

If you have long duration activity in your gRPC API, provide a stream method where you can observe progress of that activity.  (e.g. when you start the activity let it return an activity id in the response) then you can have a stream that sends responses with (id/progress fields)

Thank you, do you have any examples that does the same?

Just have a look at the C++/grpc documentation and look for "stream"
